# Datagridview (on usercontrol) painted cell revert to defaultstyle

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, user-controls, backcolor

In my program (Winforms), i use usercontrols as pages. I do this in the following way:

I have a panel on my Form1 in which i load usercontrols, on these usercontrols are my actual controls (buttons, labels, checkboxes etc). So actually i'm using the user controls as "sub" pages in my form.

The usercontrols are declared at the start of runtime, so they are "live" when i load them into the panel. This has allways worked fine, untill i ran into a problem yesterday.

Yesterday I used a datagridview on one of those usercontrols and during the ParentChanged of this control i call a Sub which changes the backcollor of this data grid view. (The sub itself is a public sub which is located in a module)

Like this:

```
Private Sub Init_ParentChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.ParentChanged
    GetRecipe(RecipeDGV, "Bla")
End Sub

Public Sub GetRecipe(ByVal Data As DataGridView, ByVal RecipeID As String)
    For r As Integer = 0 To Recipe_Mem.Rows.Count - 1
         For c As Integer = 0 To Recipe_Mem.Columns.Count - 1

              Data(c, r).Style.BackColor = getPresetColorByID(CInt(Data(c, r).Value))
              Data(c, r).ToolTipText = getPresetNameByID(CInt(Data(c, r).Value))

         NEXT
    NEXT
End Sub
```

When i run my program, i can see that my dgv gets the data from the database (which happens in the same Sub). But there is no color change in the cells.

Now, something i've noticed is that when i add a button to the user control, and use the click event of this button to call the same sub for the coloring, it does work).

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
         GetRecipe(RecipeDGV, "Bla")
End Sub
```

Any idea why this works on a button click event, but it doesn't in the usercontrol parent changed event? it looks like during the parent changed event there is some kind of repaint event of the dgv. how do i solve this?

Comment: Simple refresh issue?  Call an `Invalidate()` or `Refresh()` on the DGV or maybe even the cells themselves?

Comment: Tried that, it didn't work. It looks as if the Datagridview gets overwritten with the default cell style

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping the gridview in an ajax control ( with triggers on the ParentChanged event?

I'm a little puzzled by the "RecipeID" argument being passed as it isn't used.

Comment: Its for later purposes, the argument wil be used to filter data in the database. But is irrelevant for now.

Comment: And no, i haven't tried it, because i have no idea why this doesn't work in the first place. I want to know what happens here before i go any other direction.